# Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in php

Tags: php, pdo

```
function Checkactive($active){
$db = new Connect;
$result = '';
if(isset($active)){
  if(empty($active)){
  }else{
    $active = stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($active));
      $user = $db -> prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE active = :active");
            $user->execute(array(
                'active' => $active
            ));
            $info = $user->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            if($info['active'] != 'active'){     //line 128
              $hash = $this->generateCode(10);
                $upd = $db->prepare("UPDATE users SET active=:hash WHERE id=:ex_user");
                $upd -> execute(array(
                    'hash' => $hash,
                    'ex_user' => $info['id']    //line 133 
                ));
              echo "sucess";
          }else {
              echo "failer";
          }
    
        }
  }
return $result;
}
```

I tried to solve it but I can't.

> Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in C:\xampp\htdocs\admin\core\classes\user.Class.php on line 128

> Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in C:\xampp\htdocs\admin\core\classes\user.Class.php on line 133

```
function Checkactive($active){
$db = new Connect;
echo "first";

$result = '';
if(isset($active)){
  if(empty($active)){
  }else{
    echo $active;
    $active = stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($active));
      $user = $db -> prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE actived = :active");
            $user->execute(array('active' => $active)); //remove array('active' => $active).....then it will work normally
            $info = $user->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            
            var_dump($info);             // still return bool(false) 
          //   if( $info['actived'] == 'active'){
          //     $hash = $active;
          //       $upd = $db->prepare("UPDATE users SET actived = :hash WHERE id = :ex_user");
          //       $upd -> execute(array(
          //           'hash' => $hash,
          //           'ex_user' => $info["id"]
          //       ));
          //     echo "sucess";
          // }else {
          //   $hash = "two";
          //     var_dump($active);
          //       $upd = $db->prepare("UPDATE users SET actived = :hash WHERE id = :ex_user");
          //       $upd -> execute(array(
          //           'hash' => $hash,
          //           'ex_user' => $info["id"]
          //       ));
          //   var_dump($info);
          //   var_dump($active);
          //     echo "failer";
          // }
      }
```

}

remove array('active' => $active).....then it will work normally

Comment: that means your `$info` is returning `true` or `false`, why dont you `var_dump($info)` to see whats happening?

Comment: Note: `stripslashes()` has absolutely no business being in this code, and `htmlspecialchars()` is **only** for HTML escaping when displaying. Do not use it for SQL escaping. You're (correctly) using placeholder values which means this code is completely pointless.

Comment: Check that `execute()` succeeded. It may have failed. Tip: Turn on exceptions with `$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);`

Comment: Why are you testing `$info['active']`, your SQL query already select `active` = `$active`?

Comment: #Syscall you are right.. that is a mistake.. after removing it it works perfectly //'active' => $active \\    THANK YOU

Answer (score 0):

You have error in `$user->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)`, so it return FALSE, not array.

After, you are using `$info['active']` and `$info['id']` as an array, without result validation.

Comment: yes, it return false. pla tell me how to  change that in to array.

Comment: I can`t know what is the error, it is in Connect::fetch in your code, and you have to debug it.

Comment: remove array('active' => $active).....then it will work normally

Comment: @Syscall you are right.. that is a mistake.. after removing it it works perfectly //'active' => $active \\